# "Message rejected by Google Groups"? I am not using any Google Groups

Tags: email-bounces

Some of my email messages (sent from mydomain.com) just fail, message is returned with the following explanation:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

 info@somecompany.com

Technical details of permanent failure: 
Message rejected by Google Groups. Please visit http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 to review our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines.

----- Original message -----
```

I have no idea what Google has got to do with it?
How do I avoid this?

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The company you are sending your e-mail to is using Google Apps to host their e-mail services (check `dig -t MX somecompany.com`).
Which means you actually are sending your e-mail to Google.
That e-mail info@somecompany.com is a group alias.
But Google rejected your e-mail because it was classified as spam.

How to avoid this?
That depends on how and what kind of mails you send.
Correct SPF records can help, DKIM can help, a working unsubscribe link can help, ...

Comment: I just sent a simple "Hi, how are you..." email, with one html hyperlink and nothing more, noone in cc noone in bcc. It was not plaintext, but html email.

Comment: We don't know what Google classifies as spam and what not. Best you can do is follow https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126

Comment: I have no idea. I need to contat Google to check if my company is on some kind of a blacklist (we've been hacked lately).

Comment: Is there any way you can change google groups to reduce it's spam threshold? One of our clients can email us at our individual email addresses fine, but not to the 'google group' we have in place.